# Spark Dataframe: How to aggregate both numerical and nominal columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark Dataframes and have dataframe `df` similar to this:

```
id: String | amount: Double | donor: String
--------------------------------------------
1          | 50             | Mary
2          |100             | Michael
1          | 60             | Minnie
1          | 20             | Mark
2          | 55             | Mony
```

I want to aggregate my dataframe in one go and get this output:

```
id: String | amount: Double | donor: Seq[String]
--------------------------------------------
1          |130             | {Mary,Minnie,Mark}
2          |155             | {Michael, Mony}
```

So I want to do something like:

`df.groupyBy("id").agg(sum("amount"),_?Seq?_("donor"))`

Aggregating the sum of the numbers is easy, but I can't find a way to aggregate the text content as a Sequence or Array (or any similar type that is Iterable). How can I do this in scala/spark?

EDIT:

I am looking for some spark Dataframe or RDD based function to do the collection of strings. Functions as the below mentioned `collect_set` are Hive based and I need specific dependencies for that. But I am not using Hive at all in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupyBy("id").agg(sum("amount"), collect_list("donor"))
```

or

```
df.groupyBy("id").agg(sum("amount"), collect_set("donor"))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm but in which class did you find `collect_set` \ `collect_list`? I can't seem to find these in the API. In addition to that, is there a way to make sure the collection only has distinct values?

Comment: I found it and collect_list is a Hive function. Isn't there something native to spark because I am not using Hive.